# Does adding new SQLAlchemy.model will be automatically added to my database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I'm going to add another SQLAlchemy model, does it automatically be added to my database? Do I need to run some commands for it to be added or checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only be added if you run the `db.create_all()` command again.

If your model is going to be changing frequently it might be worth getting to grips with something like [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can handle database migrations really nicely.

Comment: Ohw ok. thank you so much. I really do think that I'm gonna change something frequently. Uhmm additional question. if I use db.create_all() again. does it gonna erase all the data which was stored already?

Comment: `db.create_all()` will only create any tables that do not exist. It's also worth noting that it won't handle changes to an existing table but will create any tables that do not exist. If you want to handle changes to an existing table/model then you'll need to use something like Flask-Migrate.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer these questions of mine. thank you so much